# Geometry of quotient of a polynomial ring

Tags: geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra, book-recommendation

I'm looking for a book about the geometry of polynomial rings. I often see in some seminars the presenters have some geometric intuition when they look at the quotient by an ideal. For example, by looking at the graph $z^2=xy$ we can understand something about  $k[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)$, like it is a domain.

My professor recommends me the book Undergraduate COmmmutative Algebra but so far I don't think it has what I want. I know this is a vague question but do you have any recommendation?

Comment: I think Andreas Gathmann's notes on algebraic geometry is the best introduction to what you are asking for. The answer is that the ring of functions on a zero set of some polynomials, is itself a quotient of a polynomial ring. There is a BUNCH of books on commutative algebra (Atiyah-MacDonald, Eisenbud, Reid, Lang, Zariski-Samuel, Matsumura, etc.), but few seem to deal with the geometry of algebraic geometry in an accessible way. Many people (myself included) have used Hartshorne as their first real book on algebraic geometry, which is a good, but way too difficult, book to start with.

Comment: Reid's UAG would probably be a better bet than his commutative algebra book.